# Parsing a JSON Response from a .Net webservice

Tags: java, .net, android, json

Just to get this out in the open I am new to JAVA, KSOAP, and JSON. So I'll try to explain this the best I can.

A while ago I created a webservice to be consumed by Blackberry Apps that we're built using the plug in for Visual Studio. Now the project I am working on, I want to consume the same webservice for Android devices. For the most part I have the base code for the Android app done and working. Here's my problem:

I can successfully call the webservice and get a response. I know from creating the webservice that it sends a JSON response. My problem is trying to parse through the JSON response. I have found a few examples that I have been suiting to my needs however I am hung up on one thing.

In the JSON each element is preceeded by "anyType" which is forcing my code to return no results (Ultimately I am binding the data to an ArrayList) Here's what I get if I "getProperty(0).toString()...

```
anyType{Artist=anyType{TrackName=Champagne Supernova;};
```

Here is the code I am using to parse the JSON Object....

```
SoapObject gr = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
        String ro = gr.getProperty(0).toString();
              //Added just to see structure of response
        Artist_Result.add(gr.toString());

        if (ro.startsWith("{"))
        {
            JSONObject JSONObj = new JSONObject(ro);
            Iterator<String> itr = JSONObj.keys();
            while (itr.hasNext())
            {
                String key = (String)itr.next();
                String value = JSONObj.getString(key);
                //bundleResult.putString(key, value);
                Artist_Result.add(value);
            }

        }
        else if (ro.startsWith("["))
        {
            JSONArr = new JSONArray(ro);
            for (int i = 0; i < JSONArr.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObj = (JSONObject)JSONArr.get(i);
                //bundleResult.putString(String.valueOf(i), JSONObj.toString());
                Artist_Result.add(JSONObj.toString());
            }
        }
```

WebService Code:

```
 [WebMethod]
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute(typeof(Artist))]
public Artist[] GetArtist(string ArtistQuery)
{
   // All the SQL Stuff Here

    SqlDataReader sReader;
    sReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    List<Artist> Artists = new List<Artist>();
    while (sReader.Read())
    {
        Artist result = new Artist();
        result.TrackName = sReader.GetString(0);

        Artists.Add(result);
    }
    sReader.Close();
    sqlConn.Close();

    return Artists.ToArray();
}

public class Artist
{
    public string TrackName;
}
```

Sample of XML Output from a browser:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <ArrayOfArtist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://bb.mcrcog.com/">
    - <Artist>
          <TrackName>Champagne Supernova</TrackName> 
      </Artist>
    - <Artist>
         <TrackName>Don't Look Back In Anger</TrackName> 
      </Artist>
    - <Artist>
          <TrackName>D'you Know What I Mean</TrackName> 
      </Artist>
    - <Artist>
          <TrackName>Go Let It Out</TrackName> 
      </Artist>
```

I have a feeling I will need to implement a Class, and Getters/Setters on the Android side. I'm just not sure how to go about doing that. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: AFAIK, that is not valid JSON, which will be contributing to your difficulty. http://json.org/

Comment: That doesn't look like valid JSON at all to me.  I doubt you'll be able to get the built in parser to do anything with that

Comment: I knew this would be a messed up project....but when I built the web service, like I said it was for Blackberry apps, using the plugin for Visual Studio....which in turn they were actually written in JavaScript, and the web service works flawlessly with the BB apps. The plug in parsed the response automatically(By using Visual Studio's "Add Web Refrence"), so I never had to deal with this, until I jumped platforms, and now I'm lost.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using the `org.json` package.
I suggest you use the `net.sf.json` package at http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/
It contains a lot more functionality and you can create a JSONObject or JSONArray from a string (or other objects like Map) with no effort with `JSONObject.fromObject(obj)` (similar for JSONArrays).

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a shot and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around I finally got a solution. Although I'm not exactly happy with it, this does display the results in a desireable format in my app. Just want to figure out how to get the child properties direct without manipulating the strings...

```
try
    {
        HttpTransportSE at = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        at.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
        at.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        SoapObject gr = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
        for(int i = 0; i < gr.getPropertyCount(); i++ )
        {
            String start = gr.getProperty(i).toString();
            int left = 18;
            int iosc = start.indexOf(";");
            String end = start.substring(left, iosc);
            Artist_Result.add(end);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This I think it will work

```
          SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

          int cols = response.getPropertyCount();

            for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
                Object objectResponse = (Object) response.getProperty(i);




                SoapObject r =(SoapObject) objectResponse;

             String   TrackName=(String) r.getProperty("TrackName").toString();

                // Get the rest of your Properties by 
                // (String) r.getProperty("PropertyName").toString();

            }
```